# How to get categories and their content recursively on Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

When i run my scraping code which scrapes https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/istanbul-adalar-maden-satilik/daire/82579-379 this site.I get my info(ilan_bilgileri) on one column in my csv file.I want to get info categories and their content recursively (each ad has different categories with differen placement) on seperate columns.What is the best way for this? I am new to scrapy and python so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.I am not allowed to put pictures on post so here is the link of csv result https://i.stack.imgur.com/XppT5.png. And here is my spider code :

````
class HurriyetEmlak(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hurriyetspider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/istanbul-adalar-maden-satilik/daire/82579-379']



    custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': "hurriyet_son.csv",
                       'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}

    def parse(self, response):
        il = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "short-info-list", " " ))]//li[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]/text()').extract()
        ilce = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "short-info-list", " " ))]//li[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2) and parent::*)]/text()').extract()
        mahalle = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "short-info-list", " " ))]//li[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 3) and parent::*)]/text()').extract()
        fiyat = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "price", " " ))]/text()').extract()
        baslik = response.css('.txt::text').extract()
        deger = response.css('.adv-info-list div span , .txt+ span::text').extract()

        scraped_info = {
            'İl': il,
            'İlçe' : ilce,
            'Mahalle' : mahalle,
            'Fiyat' : fiyat,
            'İlan Bilgileri - Başlık': baslik,
            'İlan Bilgileri - Değer' : deger
        }
        yield scraped_info  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to write all column information in one column, not in a row. If you will crawl with default CSV like

```
scrapy crawl Hurriyet -o hurriyet_son.csv
```

It will write all information in one row as you did. I think the CSV library will help you. You can do it with just act like it is a title, not content with the following code.

```
import csv


news_titles=[]  
for new in scraped_info:
    news_titles.append(new.text)

    print (news_titles)
with open('hurriyet_son.csv', 'yeni') as f:
    writer csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(news_titles)
    f.close()
```

Let me know your update.

Comment: Actually I dont want to write all info in one row.I am trying to get information categories on columns and related information under them.But some ads have different categories than others.This is why I thougt I should do it recursively